# Downloading music files to the iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to develop an application which downloads online music data (music files) and makes them available when I am offline.

Can anyone help me? What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) framework for downloading. You may also use standard NSURLRequest, but as for me it's not as easy-to-use as ASIHTTPRequest.

**Update:**
To save file, you may use Documents directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

To save loaded data into a file, use

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

To load:

```
+ (id)dataWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path
```

Comment: thank you sir but I want that once I download the music file or mp3 file .I did not need to be download again & again the same mp3  .And it available when I am offline .

Comment: thank you sir i am trying to implement this .I hope u will help me if i get any error in this code